# iOS 11 File Provider fetchThumbnailsForItemIdentifiers method is not calling

Tags: ios, ios11

I implemented File Provider for new Files app on iOS 11. I want to show my files on remote, in Files app. I can enumarete items and show in Files app but iOS shows default thumbnail for images. So I need to show my own thumbnails for images.

```
fetchThumbnailsForItemIdentifiers:requestedSize:perThumbnailCompletionHandler:completionHandler:
```

Apple explain this method like following;

> For local files, the system automatically provides thumbnails for
>   supported content types, and calls a Quick Look Preview extension to
>   get thumbnails for custom types.
>
> However, the system cannot generate thumbnails for remote items.
>   Instead, it calls this method to request thumbnails for items stored
>   on a remote sever.

I implemented that method and make api call for the thumbnails. But that method is not called so i cannot show my own thumbnails for the images.

Why this method is not called? Is there anyone have an idea about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you need to update the item's(ProviderItem) **versionIdentifier** property for the method to get called.The Apple documentation states that too. Was stuck in the same situation ;-)

Hope this helps!